# Is space-like separation transitive?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, topology, space

Suppose that events $A$ and $B$ are spacelike separated. Also suppose that events $B$ and $C$ are spacelike separated. Does this *guarantee* that $A$ and $C$ are spacelike separated? That is, is the relation of spacelike separation transitive?

Thank you.

Comment: If observer $A$ and $C$ are stood next to each other and observer $B$ is on the other side of the galaxy, $A$ and $C$ are spacelike from $B$ but timelike from each other, no?

Comment: DRAW A DIAGRAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is quite easy to have a situation where $A$ and $B$ are spacelike separated, as are $B$ and $C$, but $A$ and $B$ are timelike separated.

Consider an example with $A=(t_{0},0,0,0)$ and $B=(t_{0},d,0,0)$; clearly the separation between these two is spacelike.  However, any point $C=(t_{1},0,0,0)$ in the direct future (or past) of $A$ will be spacelike separated from $B$, as long as $d>|t_{1}-t_{0}|/c$.

(Arrangements of multiple spacetime points in which they are all pairwise spacelike separated are quite special.  They are known as "Jost points," after [Res Jost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_Jost), who used them in one of his proofs of the CPT Theorem.)